# RPM Post Install Execute with Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, rpm

I'm working on a deployment process for work and have run into a bit of a snag.  Its more of a quality of life thing than anything else.  I've been following [Hynek Schlawack's excellent guide](https://hynek.me/articles/python-app-deployment-with-native-packages/) and have gotten pretty far. The long and short of what I'm trying to do is install a python application along with a deployment of the python version I'm currently using.  I'm using [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) to build an RPM that will then be sent and installed to site.

As part of my deployment, I'd like to run some post-install scripts.  Which I can specify in fpm using the `"--post-install {SCRIPT_NAME}"` This works all well and good when the script is an actual linux script. However, I'd really like to run a python script as my post-install. I can specify an executable python script, but it fails because I believe it is trying to execute the script as: `bash my_python_script.py`

Does anyone know if there is a way to execute a python script post-install of an RPM?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `spec` file you can specify what interpreter the `%post` script is for by using the `-p` parameter, e.g. `%post -p /usr/bin/perl` .